# Warning message is shown when taking Cassy backup

Tags: scalardb

When I tried to take backups, incremental backups and consistent backups and restore them with Cassy, I could check all operations were succeeded.
Because I could see all type of backups on my S3 and restored data.
But on the Cassy Logs, I can see Warinig log every time when I took backups.
Is it any problem? Would you mind tell me how to resolve the warning?

Bellow is the logs.

```
[centos@cassy-1 provision]$ docker exec -it provision_cassy_1 cat /var/log/scalar/cassy.log
2020-07-13 07:28:00.681 [pool-43-thread-1] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0.27.0
2020-07-13 07:28:00.682 [pool-43-thread-3] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0.27.0
2020-07-13 07:28:00.683 [pool-43-thread-2] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0.27.0
2020-07-13 07:28:00.691 [pool-43-thread-1] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
2020-07-13 07:28:00.696 [pool-43-thread-2] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
2020-07-13 07:28:00.708 [pool-43-thread-3] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
2020-07-13 07:28:01.182 [pool-43-thread-2] INFO  n.s.s.c.c.direct.SessionChannel - Will request `sftp` subsystem
2020-07-13 07:28:01.273 [pool-43-thread-2] INFO  c.s.c.r.RemoteCommandExecutor - executing /opt/cassy/bin/cassy-backup --cluster-id=ScalarDL-9136173c-6d0d-47c4-aece-1ab91c4f88d1 --snapshot-id=c5337eb5-debf-4b55-9b3f-41abee6de872 --target-ip=10.42.2.92 --data-dir=/data --store-base-uri=s3://scalar-terraform-cassy-bkup-backet --store-type=AWS_S3 --keyspaces=coordinator,system_distributed,system,system_schema,reaper_db,system_auth,system_traces,scalar --backup-type=2 in 10.42.2.92
2020-07-13 07:28:01.331 [pool-43-thread-1] INFO  n.s.s.c.c.direct.SessionChannel - Will request `sftp` subsystem
2020-07-13 07:28:01.366 [pool-43-thread-1] INFO  c.s.c.r.RemoteCommandExecutor - executing /opt/cassy/bin/cassy-backup --cluster-id=ScalarDL-9136173c-6d0d-47c4-aece-1ab91c4f88d1 --snapshot-id=c5337eb5-debf-4b55-9b3f-41abee6de872 --target-ip=10.42.2.46 --data-dir=/data --store-base-uri=s3://scalar-terraform-cassy-bkup-backet --store-type=AWS_S3 --keyspaces=coordinator,system_distributed,system,system_schema,reaper_db,system_auth,system_traces,scalar --backup-type=2 in 10.42.2.46
2020-07-13 07:28:01.384 [pool-43-thread-3] INFO  n.s.s.c.c.direct.SessionChannel - Will request `sftp` subsystem
2020-07-13 07:28:01.415 [pool-43-thread-3] INFO  c.s.c.r.RemoteCommandExecutor - executing /opt/cassy/bin/cassy-backup --cluster-id=ScalarDL-9136173c-6d0d-47c4-aece-1ab91c4f88d1 --snapshot-id=c5337eb5-debf-4b55-9b3f-41abee6de872 --target-ip=10.42.2.173 --data-dir=/data --store-base-uri=s3://scalar-terraform-cassy-bkup-backet --store-type=AWS_S3 --keyspaces=coordinator,system_distributed,system,system_schema,reaper_db,system_auth,system_traces,scalar --backup-type=2 in 10.42.2.173
2020-07-13 07:28:13.122 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Disconnected - BY_APPLICATION
2020-07-13 07:28:13.361 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Disconnected - BY_APPLICATION
2020-07-13 07:28:13.366 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Disconnected - BY_APPLICATION
2020-07-13 07:28:13.473 [pool-3-thread-1] WARN  c.s.c.server.CassyServerController - com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 7E3C55C561F61336; S3 Extended Request ID: /wnmbJya8WlQVkN/o1DDz/LVfeAReP79OWguM4ZplsxjNNkuvnnjnkW+m/P+cDZbSMEadpNBxUU=), S3 Extended Request ID: /wnmbJya8WlQVkN/o1DDz/LVfeAReP79OWguM4ZplsxjNNkuvnnjnkW+m/P+cDZbSMEadpNBxUU=
com.scalar.cassy.exception.FileTransferException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 7E3C55C561F61336; S3 Extended Request ID: /wnmbJya8WlQVkN/o1DDz/LVfeAReP79OWguM4ZplsxjNNkuvnnjnkW+m/P+cDZbSMEadpNBxUU=), S3 Extended Request ID: /wnmbJya8WlQVkN/o1DDz/LVfeAReP79OWguM4ZplsxjNNkuvnnjnkW+m/P+cDZbSMEadpNBxUU=
        at com.scalar.cassy.transferer.AwsS3FileUploader.requiresUpload(AwsS3FileUploader.java:107)
        at com.scalar.cassy.transferer.AwsS3FileUploader.upload(AwsS3FileUploader.java:43)
        at com.scalar.cassy.service.MetadataDbBackupService.backup(MetadataDbBackupService.java:43)
        at com.scalar.cassy.server.CassyServerController.lambda$backupMetadata$11(CassyServerController.java:450)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 7E3C55C561F61336; S3 Extended Request ID: /wnmbJya8WlQVkN/o1DDz/LVfeAReP79OWguM4ZplsxjNNkuvnnjnkW+m/P+cDZbSMEadpNBxUU=)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4920)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4866)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1320)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1294)
        at com.scalar.cassy.transferer.AwsS3FileUploader.requiresUpload(AwsS3FileUploader.java:97)
        ... 8 common frames omitted"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue happens because Cassy master can't access S3 to store its metadata as a backup. (Cassy master syncs its metadata to a specified cloud storage.)

So what is happening is, as a backup, it was succeeded, but it failed to backup the metadata in the Cassy master.
Failing with backing up the metadata is not very critical since the metadata is still persisted in Caasy master's secondary disk. But a problem will arise when the disk is broken because the master might lose track of backups.

To resolve that, please assign a proper privilege to a Cassy master node so that it can write some data to s3.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
After I added IAM role the to Cassy instance, the warning was soleved and I could get metadata backups.

I have two additional questions.

1)
I deployed all nodes (ScalarDL, Cassandra, cassy and so on) using Terraform from scalar-labs github.
When I deployed there was no ERROR.
Why Cassy instance wasn't attached the S3's IAM?
Should I attache the IAM from AWS console every time when I deploy new Cassy?

2)
What kind of data does metadata backup include?
Even though I had failed to take metadata backup, I could restore data to Cassandra.

Comment: For the first one, it might be a bug, so let me check.
For the second one, the metadata is basically a reference to backup data. It also manages the status of backups.
https://github.com/scalar-labs/cassy/blob/master/scripts/db.schema
The metadata backup is only needed when Cassy master disk is broken.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I understood both of your answer.

Comment: @TakahiroUchidate Thank you for the feedback. For the first part, it was a bug. It is now fixed and merged into master.
https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalar-terraform/pull/171